# Does Virtualbox virtualizes a NVIDIA or a AMD Radeon graphics card?

Tags: virtualbox, graphics-card, kodi

I'd like to try-out [XBMCbuntu](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=XBMCbuntu) (the "live" version of [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/)) on Virtualbox.

Since it is offered in two version, specifically one for AMD and another for NVIDIA graphic cards, I'm puzzled on which one should I choose to use with Virtualbox; my computer has a ATI Radeon card, but if I'm not wrong the virtualized hardware is not necessarily related to the physical one.

In the virtual machine settings, I can't find any information about what chipset is used; does Virtualbox virtualizes an AMD or a NVIDIA card? And consequently, which version of XBMCbuntu should I choose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It dosen't emulate either one of them - its a 'unique' graphics card virtualbox supports with its own drivers (wikipedia has information on [what devices that virtualbox virtualises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox#Device_virtualization)). [This thread](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=156531) suggest starting with the nvidia version, installing virtualbox guest tools, with some settings tweaks (enabling openGL), setting up the virtualbox guest drivers and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as ATI has been acquired and is owned by AMD, I would go for the AMD option. If you poke around the virtualbox website you may even discover how to set up graphics card pass through which would benefit the graphics even more.